# Difference between output of dmesg and content of /var/log/dmesg?

Tags: linux, dmesg

I found the output of `dmesg` and content of `/var/log/dmesg` are different. Then what differences are between their purposes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `dmesg` command shows the current content of the kernel syslog ring buffer messages while the `/var/log/dmesg` file contains what was in that ring buffer when the boot process last completed.

Comment: if my wireless adapter stops working after a while after startup, which one shall I look into?

Comment: @Tim: First look in `dmesg` for recent events. If you can't find it there but you still suspect that there should be relevant information, then go look in `/var/log/dmesg`.

Comment: @Tim syslog messages are stored in /var/log/syslog  then rotated in /var/log/syslog.1, /var/log/syslog.2.gz and so on.

Comment: So @jlliagre - /var/log/dmesg content will be fixed (on, e.g. server which has uptime of e.g. more than 30 days) and there is no way that the lines will change in it until the new boot? And dmesg will contain current content of the kernel syslog ring buffer, so messages in it are being replaced by the new ones? And also, where the old messages from dmesg go?

Comment: @MuhamedHuseinbašić /var/log/dmesg stays unchanged until next reboot (although a distro is free to do whatever it wants.) Old mesgs are replaced by new messages in the ring buffer, that's the idea of a ring. Old messages might be written somewhere depending on syslog configuration, other ones will be lost.

Comment: Thanks.  Why does my /var/log/dmesg show only `(Nothing has been logged yet.)`? I was expecting it has the fixed content of log information until the boot process completed.