# Capturing kernel error/stack trace after running a command in bash

Tags: bash, kernel

I'm trying to capture what looks like a kernel error/stack trace when I run the command `sudo zpool import`. There error starts with:

> [104.877657] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000ffff4167
>
> ...

I've tried [simply redirecting `stderr` to a file with `sudo zpool import &> err_file`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file) but that doesn't seem to capture it (I'm using bash) - the error still prints to the screen.

How can I grab the entire error message?

Comment: You will most probably need to redirect the error to the file as at the moment, it is redirecting to screen and so use "sudo zpool import 2> err_file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't being written to the console by the zpool command. The kernel is writing the message. It's most likely being written to the console via syslog/rsyslog.

You might be able to find the error message by running `dmesg` which will print the kernel messages. `dmesg > err_file`

Comment: Ah that shows it. Great! I actually forgot to mention I checked `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` but didn't see it in there. Why is it showing up when I run the command `dmesg` instead of in the log files?

Comment: OK, answering my own question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191560/difference-between-output-of-dmesg-and-content-of-var-log-dmesg